# How to enable/disable a button on change of a cell value in datagridview in c# net

Tags: c#, .net, events, c#-4.0, datagridview

How to enable/disable a button on change of  a cell value in datagridview in c# net
On which event of datagridview, I should write my code?

Thanks in Advance,
Swarna

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
                                            DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // enable/disable a button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  if(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "YourColumnName"){
    // enable/disable a button
  }
}
```

or

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
  if(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "YourColumnName"){
    // enable/disable a button
  }
}
```